# Geocoding Service is not returning any result for the US Zip Code 90210

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

The Geocoding Service is not returning any result for the US Zip Code 90210, which is the zip code for “BEVERLY HILLS CA”.

But the Geocoding is working for other US zip codes. Kindly help me here.
Please let me know if you have any questions.

https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=***********************************&address=90210

Comment: As mentioned in https://issuetracker.google.com/73030863, please use [Component Filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding#component-filtering) for a much better results when searching for 5-digit zip codes in the US. For example, searching zip code 90210 with this request: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:90210|country:US&key=key

Answer (score 6):

I'm glad you posted this question, I was having the same issue.  I used rafon's answer and added `|country:US` at the end of the url and it worked perfectly.

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key={KEY}&components=postal_code:90210|country:US
```